# If a website loads a product on the back end but does not publish it for the public yet, can I access that information?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to web scraping and am trying to learn more. I know some websites load products on the back end before they make it available to the general public. Is there a way I can access that information using an HTML parser or any other library?

I suspect the website developers use dynamic javascript to alter the information after loading. Or use different tags/classes to hide the information?

Comment: The "back end" is server-side. Information that's supposed to be hidden would not be sent to the client at all (if the developers are at all competent). A scraper can only see what you see in the network tab of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Your question is too unspecific to be answered here. There can be a different answer for every single website with a backend out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two questions here:

1)Can I access information on the webserver that isn't sent to the client page?

*No*. You can only scrape what exists on the page. Anything else would be illegally accessing a non-public server and goes beyond scraping into hacking.

2) If the site loads asynchronously and/or dynamically, can I access the content that loads after the main portion of the html?

Yes, using browser automation tools like selenium, you can approximate a user experiencing the site and wait for the full content to load before you scrape it. This is different from simple requests/beautifulsoup, which only gathers the HTML at the point when you send the request.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Is it common for modern websites to load dynamically? What content would I miss out on if I used beautifulsoup on a dynamically loaded site?

Comment: 1) It's very common, and getting more common (partially to combat simple scraping) 2) It depends on the site, and how much of their content is generated via AJAX, etc. For example, one site I use I can use requests and get all but one or two page elements, while another I'll only get the page title and footer, all other content is generated on the fly.