# R Web Scrape of Dynamically Generated Table with a form method="post"

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, httr

I am extremely novice when it comes to web scraping.
I am trying to do some exploratory analytics on some public base salary information where I work.  They have a website, but it is awful trying to get any information out of it (almost like they did it on purpose...). Reading some intro to web scraping tutorials in R, I think this is an embedded table; the formatting looks like it is from Tableau.
After reading this post, I also think it is dynamic since the table isn't generated right away when the webpage is opened. When I inspect the webpage it has a form method="post" and that seems to make things harder from the little bit of reading I have done.

[If a website loads a product on the back end but does not publish it for the public yet, can I access that information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56382627/if-a-website-loads-a-product-on-the-back-end-but-does-not-publish-it-for-the-pub?rq=1)

Due to this post, I think I need to use the package httr for a post request. But trying to read through this is making my head spin.
https://f.briatte.org/r/scraping-form-results-with-httr

Now I am just realizing "All Campuses" the default is fine; I can filter later in R. So I just need to push the "Search" with httr.

Is there any way to scrape this information? I am most fluent in R if it is possible to do it there.

The website I am trying to scrape:
https://www.cusys.edu/budget/cusalaries/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using RSelenium. Here is an example :

```
library(RSelenium)
url <- "https://www.cusys.edu/budget/cusalaries/"
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)

web_Obj <- remDr$findElement("xpath", '/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/div[1]/div/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/input') #search button
web_Obj$clickElement()

web_Obj_Table <- remDr$findElement("xpath", '/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/div[1]/div/div/form/div/div/div/table[1]')
text_Table <- web_Obj_Table$getElementText()[[1]]
strsplit(text_Table, "\n")

[[1]]
 [1] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ ASA-Ctr Intrntl Bus/Ed/Rsch ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-122954 Director-Faculty Administrative Faculty 2.5 $60,000.00"                         
 [2] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ ASA-Ctr Intrntl Bus/Ed/Rsch ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-111214 Business Services Asst Dir Univ Staff - Business Services 100 $72,000.00"       
 [3] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ ASA-Ctr Intrntl Bus/Ed/Rsch ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-114090 Business Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Business Services 100 $54,000.00"    
 [4] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVC OARS-NVTI ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-123858 Lecturer Other Faculty 50 $0.00"                                                              
 [5] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVC OARS-OO OMBUDSMAN OFFICE ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-121705 Academic Services Assoc Dir Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $95,822.76"     
 [6] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVC OARS-OO OMBUDSMAN OFFICE ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-109738 Academic Services Assoc Dir Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $85,285.08"     
 [7] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVC OARS-OO OMBUDSMAN OFFICE ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-125075 Academic Services Director Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $108,289.68"     
 [8] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCAP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESS ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-100138 Business Services Assoc Dir Univ Staff - Business Services 100 $85,000.00"        
 [9] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCAP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESS ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-119011 Business Services Professional Univ Staff - Business Services 100 $67,000.00"     
[10] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCAP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESS ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-103367 Business Services Professional Univ Staff - Business Services 100 $65,000.00"     
[11] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCAP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESS ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-120088 Business Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Business Services 100 $82,081.92"      
[12] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCAP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESS ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-119368 Business Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Business Services 100 $80,480.88"      
[13] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCAP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESS ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-110281 Business Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Business Services 100 $75,000.00"      
[14] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCAP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESS ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-124082 Asst Vice Chancellor Univ Staff - Executive 100 $157,000.00"                      
[15] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCAP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESS ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-122661 Executive Director Univ Staff - Executive 100 $140,000.00"                        
[16] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCAP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESS ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-119303 IT Principal Prof Univ Staff - Information Tech. 50 $46,278.96"                   
[17] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-CH Campus Housing ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-108478 Business Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Business Services 100 $55,000.00"       
[18] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-CH Campus Housing ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-103171 Executive Director Univ Staff - Executive 100 $102,000.00"                         
[19] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-CH Campus Housing ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-110700 Student Service Assoc Director Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $75,000.00"       
[20] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-CH Campus Housing ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-109706 Student Service Assoc Director Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $80,000.00"       
[21] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-CH Campus Housing ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-103169 Student Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $42,729.12"         
[22] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-CH Campus Housing ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-102105 Student Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $42,729.00"         
[23] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-CH Campus Housing ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-101263 Student Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $42,729.00"         
[24] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-CH Campus Housing ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-101116 Student Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $42,729.00"         
[25] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-CH Campus Housing ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-109348 Finance/Acctg Senior Prof Univ Staff- Finance & Acct. 100 $52,800.00"              
[26] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DO Diversity Office ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-100015 Executive Assistant Univ Staff- Prof. Support Sr 100 $72,000.00"                 
[27] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DO Educatnl Opportunity ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-121508 Technician III Class Staff-Professional Srvce 100 $60,684.00"                
[28] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DO Educatnl Opportunity ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-122605 Student Services Prgm Director Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $64,503.96" 
[29] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DO Educatnl Opportunity ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-116274 Student Services Prgm Director Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $65,585.04" 
[30] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Dean of Students ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-108225 Business Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Business Services 100 $48,136.68"    
[31] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Dean of Students ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-112560 Student Service Assoc Director Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $75,000.00"    
[32] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Dean of Students ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-114054 Student Services Director Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $90,385.00"         
[33] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Dean of Students ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-112128 Student Services Prgm Director Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $70,009.92"    
[34] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Dean of Students ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-106671 Student Services Prgm Manager Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $57,500.04"     
[35] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Dean of Students ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-115935 Student Services Professional Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $50,000.00"     
[36] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Dean of Students ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-102357 Student Services Professional Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $50,000.00"     
[37] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Dean of Students ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-100443 Student Services Professional Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $50,000.00"     
[38] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS PhoenixCtr at Aurar ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-109956 Student Services Prgm Director Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $70,000.00" 
[39] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS PhoenixCtr at Aurar ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-108692 Student Services Prgm Manager Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $54,550.00"  
[40] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS PhoenixCtr at Aurar ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-105423 Student Services Professional Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $50,000.00"  
[41] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS PhoenixCtr at Aurar ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-104981 Student Services Professional Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $50,000.00"  
[42] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Stdnt&Comm Counseln ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-122385 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $60,534.00"
[43] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Stdnt&Comm Counseln ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-100159 Student Services Asst Director Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $69,178.92" 
[44] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Stdnt&Comm Counseln ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-117580 Student Services Director Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $95,693.04"      
[45] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Stdnt&Comm Counseln ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-111326 Student Services Professional Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $60,088.08"  
[46] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Stdnt&Comm Counseln ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-102554 Student Services Professional Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $56,000.00"  
[47] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Stdnt&Comm Counseln ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-102485 Student Services Professional Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $56,000.00"  
[48] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Stdnt&Comm Counseln ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-122396 Student Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Student Services 50 $31,239.00"    
[49] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Stdnt&Comm Counseln ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-115308 Student Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $63,500.00"   
[50] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-116557 Admin Assistant II Class Staff-Admin Support 100 $38,484.00"
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This was a great start :) It took me a while to figure out what I needed to download to get the code to run, but it work!
I do have a follow-up question; this pulls the first 50, which is all that is displayed, so that makes sense. Do I need to write a loop that clicks the "Next Page" button to get the rest of the dataset? Or is there an easier way that I am not thinking of?

Comment: Yes, you can do this. I will provide you an example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that can be considered :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
url <- "https://www.cusys.edu/budget/cusalaries/"
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate(url)
Sys.sleep(5)
doc <- IEApp$Document()

clickEvent <- doc$createEvent("MouseEvent")
clickEvent$initEvent("click", TRUE, FALSE)

id <- stringr::str_extract_all(html_Content, 'id=\"searchID_.*\" type')[[1]]
id <- stringr::str_remove_all(id, 'id=\"|\"| type')

web_Obj <- doc$getElementByID(id)
web_Obj$dispatchEvent(clickEvent)

id_Table <- paste0("cbTable_", tail(unlist(strsplit(id, "_")), 1))
web_Obj_Table <- doc$getElementByID(id_Table)
text_Table <- read_html(web_Obj_Table$innerHtml()) %>% html_text()
strsplit(text_Table, "DENVER & ANSCHUTZAVC")

 strsplit(text_Table, "DENVER & ANSCHUTZAVC|DENVER & ANSCHUTZASA")
[[1]]
 [1] "\n\n\n\n\n Search Again  Sort by CAMPUS (A to Z)JOB FAMILY (A to Z)JOB TITLE (A to Z)JOB FULL TIME PCNT (Low to High)TOTAL FUNDING (Low to High)SCHOOL/COLLEGE/FUNCTION (A to Z)CAMPUSSCHOOL/COLLEGE/FUNCTIONDEPARTMENT GROUPROSTER IDJOB TITLEJOB FAMILYJOB FULL TIME PCNTTOTAL FUNDING"                                                                                                                                             
 [2] "-Ctr Intrntl Bus/Ed/RschACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-122954Director-FacultyAdministrative Faculty2.5$60,000.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 [3] "-Ctr Intrntl Bus/Ed/RschACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-111214Business Services Asst DirUniv Staff - Business Services100$72,000.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 [4] "-Ctr Intrntl Bus/Ed/RschACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-114090Business Services Senior ProfUniv Staff - Business Services100$54,000.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 [5] " OARS-NVTIACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-123858LecturerOther Faculty50$0.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 [6] " OARS-OO OMBUDSMAN OFFICEACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-121705Academic Services Assoc DirUniv Staff - Academic Services100$95,822.76"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 [7] " OARS-OO OMBUDSMAN OFFICEACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-109738Academic Services Assoc DirUniv Staff - Academic Services100$85,285.08"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 [8] " OARS-OO OMBUDSMAN OFFICEACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-125075Academic Services DirectorUniv Staff - Academic Services100$108,289.68"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 [9] "AP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESSACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-100138Business Services Assoc DirUniv Staff - Business Services100$85,000.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
[10] "AP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESSACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-119011Business Services ProfessionalUniv Staff - Business Services100$67,000.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[11] "AP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESSACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-103367Business Services ProfessionalUniv Staff - Business Services100$65,000.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[12] "AP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESSACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-120088Business Services Senior ProfUniv Staff - Business Services100$82,081.92"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[13] "AP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESSACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-119368Business Services Senior ProfUniv Staff - Business Services100$80,480.88"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[14] "AP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESSACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-110281Business Services Senior ProfUniv Staff - Business Services100$75,000.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[15] "AP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESSACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-124082Asst Vice ChancellorUniv Staff - Executive100$157,000.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[16] "AP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESSACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-122661Executive DirectorUniv Staff - Executive100$140,000.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
[17] "AP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESSACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-119303IT Principal ProfUniv Staff - Information Tech.50$46,278.96"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[18] "ASA-CH Campus HousingACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-108478Business Services Senior ProfUniv Staff - Business Services100$55,000.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[19] "ASA-CH Campus HousingACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-103171Executive DirectorUniv Staff - Executive100$102,000.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[20] "ASA-CH Campus HousingACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-110700Student Service Assoc DirectorUniv Staff - Student Services100$75,000.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[21] "ASA-CH Campus HousingACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-109706Student Service Assoc DirectorUniv Staff - Student Services100$80,000.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[22] "ASA-CH Campus HousingACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-103169Student Services Senior ProfUniv Staff - Student Services100$42,729.12"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[23] "ASA-CH Campus HousingACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-102105Student Services Senior ProfUniv Staff - Student Services100$42,729.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[24] "ASA-CH Campus HousingACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-101263Student Services Senior ProfUniv Staff - Student Services100$42,729.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[25] "ASA-CH Campus HousingACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-101116Student Services Senior ProfUniv Staff - Student Services100$42,729.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[26] "ASA-CH Campus HousingACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-109348Finance/Acctg Senior ProfUniv Staff- Finance & Acct.100$52,800.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[27] "ASA-DO Diversity OfficeACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-100015Executive AssistantUniv Staff- Prof. Support Sr100$72,000.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
[28] "ASA-DO Educatnl OpportunityACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-121508Technician IIIClass Staff-Professional Srvce100$60,684.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
[29] "ASA-DO Educatnl OpportunityACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-122605Student Services Prgm DirectorUniv Staff - Student Services100$64,503.96"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
[30] "ASA-DO Educatnl OpportunityACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-116274Student Services Prgm DirectorUniv Staff - Student Services100$65,585.04"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
[31] "ASA-DOS Dean of StudentsACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-108225Business Services Senior ProfUniv Staff - Business Services100$48,136.68"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[32] "ASA-DOS Dean of StudentsACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-112560Student Service Assoc DirectorUniv Staff - Student Services100$75,000.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[33] "ASA-DOS Dean of StudentsACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-114054Student Services DirectorUniv Staff - Student Services100$90,385.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[34] "ASA-DOS Dean of StudentsACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-112128Student Services Prgm DirectorUniv Staff - Student Services100$70,009.92"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[35] "ASA-DOS Dean of StudentsACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-106671Student Services Prgm ManagerUniv Staff - Student Services100$57,500.04"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[36] "ASA-DOS Dean of StudentsACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-115935Student Services ProfessionalUniv Staff - Student Services100$50,000.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[37] "ASA-DOS Dean of StudentsACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-102357Student Services ProfessionalUniv Staff - Student Services100$50,000.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[38] "ASA-DOS Dean of StudentsACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-100443Student Services ProfessionalUniv Staff - Student Services100$50,000.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[39] "ASA-DOS PhoenixCtr at AurarACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-109956Student Services Prgm DirectorUniv Staff - Student Services100$70,000.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
[40] "ASA-DOS PhoenixCtr at AurarACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-108692Student Services Prgm ManagerUniv Staff - Student Services100$54,550.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[41] "ASA-DOS PhoenixCtr at AurarACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-105423Student Services ProfessionalUniv Staff - Student Services100$50,000.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[42] "ASA-DOS PhoenixCtr at AurarACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-104981Student Services ProfessionalUniv Staff - Student Services100$50,000.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[43] "ASA-DOS Stdnt&Comm CounselnACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-122385Academic Services ProfessionalUniv Staff - Academic Services100$60,534.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
[44] "ASA-DOS Stdnt&Comm CounselnACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-100159Student Services Asst DirectorUniv Staff - Student Services100$69,178.92"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
[45] "ASA-DOS Stdnt&Comm CounselnACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-117580Student Services DirectorUniv Staff - Student Services100$95,693.04"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[46] "ASA-DOS Stdnt&Comm CounselnACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-111326Student Services ProfessionalUniv Staff - Student Services100$60,088.08"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[47] "ASA-DOS Stdnt&Comm CounselnACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-102554Student Services ProfessionalUniv Staff - Student Services100$56,000.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[48] "ASA-DOS Stdnt&Comm CounselnACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-102485Student Services ProfessionalUniv Staff - Student Services100$56,000.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[49] "ASA-DOS Stdnt&Comm CounselnACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-122396Student Services Senior ProfUniv Staff - Student Services50$31,239.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[50] "ASA-DOS Stdnt&Comm CounselnACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-115308Student Services Senior ProfUniv Staff - Student Services100$63,500.00"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[51] "ASA-EM AdmissionsACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRSR21-116557Admin Assistant IIClass Staff-Admin Support100$38,484.00CAMPUSSCHOOL/COLLEGE/FUNCTIONDEPARTMENT GROUPROSTER IDJOB TITLEJOB FAMILYJOB FULL TIME PCNTTOTAL FUNDING Page    of 601  Records 1-50 of 30011   Search Again  Sort by CAMPUS (A to Z)JOB FAMILY (A to Z)JOB TITLE (A to Z)JOB FULL TIME PCNT (Low to High)TOTAL FUNDING (Low to High)SCHOOL/COLLEGE/FUNCTION (A to Z)\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach that you can consider to loop over the pages with the R package RSelenium :

```
library(RSelenium)
url <- "https://www.cusys.edu/budget/cusalaries/"
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)

web_Obj <- remDr$findElement("xpath", '/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/div[1]/div/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/input') #search button
web_Obj$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(5)

web_Obj_Table <- remDr$findElement("xpath", '/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/div[1]/div/div/form/div/div/div/table[1]')
text_Table <- web_Obj_Table$getElementText()[[1]]

list_Text_Table <- list()
list_Text_Table[[1]] <- strsplit(text_Table, "\n")

for(i in 1 : 3)
{
  print(i)
  
  if(i == 1)
  {
    full_Xpath <- '/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/div[1]/div/div/form/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/a/img'
    
  }else
  {
    full_Xpath <- '/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/div[1]/div/div/form/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[6]/a/img'
  }
  
  web_Obj_Next_Page <- remDr$findElement("xpath", full_Xpath)
  web_Obj_Next_Page$clickElement()
  Sys.sleep(5)
  
  web_Obj_Table <- remDr$findElement("xpath", '/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/div[1]/div/div/form/div/div/div/table[1]')
  text_Table <- web_Obj_Table$getElementText()[[1]]
  list_Text_Table[[i + 1]] <- strsplit(text_Table, "\n")
}

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
 [1] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ ASA-Ctr Intrntl Bus/Ed/Rsch ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-122954 Director-Faculty Administrative Faculty 2.5 $60,000.00"                         
 [2] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ ASA-Ctr Intrntl Bus/Ed/Rsch ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-111214 Business Services Asst Dir Univ Staff - Business Services 100 $72,000.00"       
 [3] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ ASA-Ctr Intrntl Bus/Ed/Rsch ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-114090 Business Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Business Services 100 $54,000.00"    
 [4] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVC OARS-NVTI ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-123858 Lecturer Other Faculty 50 $0.00"                                                              
 [5] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVC OARS-OO OMBUDSMAN OFFICE ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-121705 Academic Services Assoc Dir Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $95,822.76"     
 [6] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVC OARS-OO OMBUDSMAN OFFICE ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-109738 Academic Services Assoc Dir Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $85,285.08"     
 [7] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVC OARS-OO OMBUDSMAN OFFICE ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-125075 Academic Services Director Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $108,289.68"     
 [8] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCAP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESS ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-100138 Business Services Assoc Dir Univ Staff - Business Services 100 $85,000.00"        
 [9] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCAP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESS ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-119011 Business Services Professional Univ Staff - Business Services 100 $67,000.00"     
[10] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCAP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESS ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-103367 Business Services Professional Univ Staff - Business Services 100 $65,000.00"     
[11] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCAP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESS ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-120088 Business Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Business Services 100 $82,081.92"      
[12] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCAP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESS ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-119368 Business Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Business Services 100 $80,480.88"      
[13] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCAP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESS ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-110281 Business Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Business Services 100 $75,000.00"      
[14] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCAP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESS ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-124082 Asst Vice Chancellor Univ Staff - Executive 100 $157,000.00"                      
[15] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCAP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESS ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-122661 Executive Director Univ Staff - Executive 100 $140,000.00"                        
[16] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCAP-I/R & EFFECTIVENESS ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-119303 IT Principal Prof Univ Staff - Information Tech. 50 $46,278.96"                   
[17] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-CH Campus Housing ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-108478 Business Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Business Services 100 $55,000.00"       
[18] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-CH Campus Housing ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-103171 Executive Director Univ Staff - Executive 100 $102,000.00"                         
[19] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-CH Campus Housing ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-110700 Student Service Assoc Director Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $75,000.00"       
[20] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-CH Campus Housing ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-109706 Student Service Assoc Director Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $80,000.00"       
[21] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-CH Campus Housing ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-103169 Student Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $42,729.12"         
[22] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-CH Campus Housing ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-102105 Student Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $42,729.00"         
[23] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-CH Campus Housing ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-101263 Student Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $42,729.00"         
[24] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-CH Campus Housing ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-101116 Student Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $42,729.00"         
[25] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-CH Campus Housing ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-109348 Finance/Acctg Senior Prof Univ Staff- Finance & Acct. 100 $52,800.00"              
[26] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DO Diversity Office ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-100015 Executive Assistant Univ Staff- Prof. Support Sr 100 $72,000.00"                 
[27] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DO Educatnl Opportunity ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-121508 Technician III Class Staff-Professional Srvce 100 $60,684.00"                
[28] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DO Educatnl Opportunity ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-122605 Student Services Prgm Director Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $64,503.96" 
[29] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DO Educatnl Opportunity ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-116274 Student Services Prgm Director Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $65,585.04" 
[30] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Dean of Students ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-108225 Business Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Business Services 100 $48,136.68"    
[31] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Dean of Students ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-112560 Student Service Assoc Director Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $75,000.00"    
[32] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Dean of Students ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-114054 Student Services Director Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $90,385.00"         
[33] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Dean of Students ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-112128 Student Services Prgm Director Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $70,009.92"    
[34] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Dean of Students ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-106671 Student Services Prgm Manager Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $57,500.04"     
[35] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Dean of Students ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-115935 Student Services Professional Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $50,000.00"     
[36] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Dean of Students ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-102357 Student Services Professional Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $50,000.00"     
[37] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Dean of Students ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-100443 Student Services Professional Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $50,000.00"     
[38] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS PhoenixCtr at Aurar ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-109956 Student Services Prgm Director Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $70,000.00" 
[39] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS PhoenixCtr at Aurar ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-108692 Student Services Prgm Manager Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $54,550.00"  
[40] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS PhoenixCtr at Aurar ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-105423 Student Services Professional Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $50,000.00"  
[41] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS PhoenixCtr at Aurar ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-104981 Student Services Professional Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $50,000.00"  
[42] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Stdnt&Comm Counseln ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-122385 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $60,534.00"
[43] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Stdnt&Comm Counseln ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-100159 Student Services Asst Director Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $69,178.92" 
[44] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Stdnt&Comm Counseln ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-117580 Student Services Director Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $95,693.04"      
[45] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Stdnt&Comm Counseln ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-111326 Student Services Professional Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $60,088.08"  
[46] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Stdnt&Comm Counseln ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-102554 Student Services Professional Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $56,000.00"  
[47] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Stdnt&Comm Counseln ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-102485 Student Services Professional Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $56,000.00"  
[48] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Stdnt&Comm Counseln ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-122396 Student Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Student Services 50 $31,239.00"    
[49] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-DOS Stdnt&Comm Counseln ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-115308 Student Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $63,500.00"   
[50] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-116557 Admin Assistant II Class Staff-Admin Support 100 $38,484.00"                           


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
 [1] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-114189 Admin Assistant II Class Staff-Admin Support 100 $36,144.00"                          
 [2] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-116435 Admin Assistant III Class Staff-Admin Support 100 $46,980.00"                         
 [3] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-123352 Student Services Specialst III Class Staff-Professional Srvce 100 $60,312.00"         
 [4] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-109976 Academic Services Assoc Dir Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $66,969.00"            
 [5] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-101364 Academic Services Assoc Dir Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $68,500.00"            
 [6] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-123774 Academic Services Asst Dir Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $63,588.24"             
 [7] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-102849 Academic Services Asst Dir Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $58,480.00"             
 [8] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-102829 Academic Services Director Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $95,000.00"             
 [9] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-114499 Academic Services Entry Prof Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $40,000.00"           
[10] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-113974 Academic Services Entry Prof Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $49,500.00"           
[11] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-106588 Academic Services Entry Prof Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $43,000.00"           
[12] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-118534 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $53,624.04"         
[13] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-118427 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $48,759.96"         
[14] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-117806 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $47,000.00"         
[15] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-112832 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $39,834.36"         
[16] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-110385 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $43,500.00"         
[17] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-110359 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $43,500.00"         
[18] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-108129 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $43,000.00"         
[19] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-105865 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $43,500.00"         
[20] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-103699 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $44,000.00"         
[21] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-100467 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $44,000.00"         
[22] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-102964 IT Asst Dir Univ Staff - Information Tech. 100 $85,000.00"                            
[23] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Admissions ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-101366 Student Services Professional Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $40,000.00"           
[24] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM FA FINANCIAL AID ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-125012 Student Services Specialist IV Class Staff-Professional Srvce 100 $72,216.00"   
[25] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM FA FINANCIAL AID ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-123915 Student Services Specialst III Class Staff-Professional Srvce 100 $75,120.00"   
[26] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM FA FINANCIAL AID ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-124316 Academic Services Assoc Dir Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $79,593.96"      
[27] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM FA FINANCIAL AID ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-113256 Academic Services Assoc Dir Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $80,554.92"      
[28] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM FA FINANCIAL AID ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-119579 Academic Services Asst Dir Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $71,048.04"       
[29] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM FA FINANCIAL AID ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-118887 Academic Services Asst Dir Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $68,900.76"       
[30] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM FA FINANCIAL AID ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-123581 Academic Services Director Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $95,000.00"       
[31] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM FA FINANCIAL AID ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-119509 Academic Services Entry Prof Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $41,920.80"     
[32] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM FA FINANCIAL AID ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-118949 Academic Services Entry Prof Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $44,652.60"     
[33] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM FA FINANCIAL AID ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-116554 Academic Services Entry Prof Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $41,000.00"     
[34] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM FA FINANCIAL AID ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-119162 Academic Services Principal Pr Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $56,556.84"   
[35] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM FA FINANCIAL AID ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-115057 Academic Services Principal Pr Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $59,297.16"   
[36] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM FA FINANCIAL AID ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-113780 Academic Services Principal Pr Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $55,737.84"   
[37] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM FA FINANCIAL AID ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-124076 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 50 $24,622.68"    
[38] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM FA FINANCIAL AID ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-106755 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $41,024.04"   
[39] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM FA FINANCIAL AID ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-122162 Academic Services Program Mgr Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $68,455.80"    
[40] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM FA FINANCIAL AID ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-120585 Academic Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $66,286.32"    
[41] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM FA FINANCIAL AID ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-116525 Academic Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $51,300.00"    
[42] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM FA FINANCIAL AID ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-100142 Asst Vice Chancellor Univ Staff - Executive 100 $124,194.00"                    
[43] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM FA FINANCIAL AID ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-102231 Student Services Professional Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $48,000.00"     
[44] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Pre Collegiate Devel ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-119628 Academic Services Program Mgr Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $53,591.47"
[45] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Pre Collegiate Devel ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-119594 Academic Services Program Mgr Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $51,737.00"
[46] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Pre Collegiate Devel ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-100976 Academic Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $44,500.00"
[47] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM Pre Collegiate Devel ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-122912 Student Services Director Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $87,837.00"     
[48] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-EM UNDERGRADSCHLRSHPOFC ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-118494 Academic Services Assoc Dir Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $68,000.00"  
[49] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Ctr for Fac Develo ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-105195 Program Assistant I Class Staff-Professional Srvce 100 $49,104.00"          
[50] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Ctr for Fac Develo ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-116251 Program Assistant I US-Auxilliary Funding (CS) 100 $49,500.00"              


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
 [1] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Experiential Learn ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-121183 Academic Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $62,494.56"
 [2] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Experiential Learn ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-105881 Business Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Business Services 100 $50,000.00"
 [3] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Experiential Learn ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-116021 Student Services Professional Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $50,000.00" 
 [4] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Experiential Learn ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-108171 Student Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Student Services 100 $53,175.00"  
 [5] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE FacAffrs/UG Enrich ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-125084 Academic Services Director Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $116,112.00"  
 [6] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Honors&Leaders Pro ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-124503 Lecturer Other Faculty 2.5 $27,000.00"                                      
 [7] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Honors&Leaders Pro ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-118011 Lecturer Other Faculty 25 $14,400.00"                                       
 [8] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Honors&Leaders Pro ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-101392 Lecturer Other Faculty 25 $32,000.00"                                       
 [9] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Undergrad Experi ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-114393 Director-Faculty Administrative Faculty 49 $59,353.00"                        
[10] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Undergrad Experi ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-125318 Lecturer Other Faculty 10 $21,600.00"                                         
[11] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Undergrad Experi ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-124139 Lecturer Other Faculty 10 $15,000.00"                                         
[12] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Undergrad Experi ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-122405 Lecturer Other Faculty 10 $16,500.00"                                         
[13] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Undergrad Experi ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-121806 Lecturer Other Faculty 10 $16,500.00"                                         
[14] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Undergrad Experi ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-120785 Lecturer Other Faculty 10 $0.00"                                              
[15] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Undergrad Experi ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-119687 Lecturer Other Faculty 10 $15,000.00"                                         
[16] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Undergrad Experi ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-118451 Lecturer Other Faculty 10 $30,000.00"                                         
[17] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Undergrad Experi ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-116937 Lecturer Other Faculty 10 $16,500.00"                                         
[18] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Undergrad Experi ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-116468 Lecturer Other Faculty 10 $16,500.00"                                         
[19] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Undergrad Experi ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-114999 Lecturer Other Faculty 10 $15,000.00"                                         
[20] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Undergrad Experi ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-112669 Lecturer Other Faculty 10 $16,500.00"                                         
[21] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Undergrad Experi ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-108751 Lecturer Other Faculty 10 $16,500.00"                                         
[22] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Undergrad Experi ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-106218 Lecturer Other Faculty 10 $16,500.00"                                         
[23] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Undergrad Experi ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-121184 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $60,631.92" 
[24] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Undergrad Experi ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-111364 Assoc Vice Chancellor Univ Staff - Executive 100 $168,259.00"                 
[25] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Undergrad Experi ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-109824 Asst Vice Chancellor Univ Staff - Executive 100 $110,000.00"                  
[26] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Undergrad Experi ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-112089 Student Services Director Univ Staff - Student Services 50 $37,000.00"        
[27] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-FAUE Undergrad Experi ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-116047 Executive Assistant Univ Staff- Prof. Support Sr 100 $56,274.60"              
[28] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-OIA Intl Education ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-124187 Academic Services Assoc Dir Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $75,828.00"       
[29] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-OIA Intl Education ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-121619 Academic Services Director Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $99,561.00"        
[30] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-OIA Intl Education ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-115726 Academic Services Director Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $82,000.00"        
[31] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-OIA Intl Education ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-103912 Academic Services Director Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $125,000.00"       
[32] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-OIA Intl Education ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-121982 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $49,000.00"    
[33] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-OIA Intl Education ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-114173 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $48,500.00"    
[34] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-OIA Intl Education ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-112066 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $47,500.00"    
[35] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-OIA Intl Education ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-109484 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $47,500.00"    
[36] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-OIA Intl Education ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-108420 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $47,500.00"    
[37] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-OIA Intl Education ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-105664 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $47,500.00"    
[38] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-OIA Intl Education ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-105319 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $47,500.00"    
[39] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-OIA Intl Education ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-105129 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $47,500.00"    
[40] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-OIA Intl Education ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-101614 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $50,000.00"    
[41] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-OIA Intl Education ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-101152 Academic Services Professional Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $49,000.00"    
[42] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-OIA Intl Education ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-106291 Academic Services Program Mgr Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $60,000.00"     
[43] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-OIA Intl Education ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-101070 Academic Services Program Mgr Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $60,000.00"     
[44] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-OIA Intl Education ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-114135 Academic Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $54,936.96"     
[45] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-OIA Intl Education ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-113409 Academic Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Academic Services 100 $49,200.00"     
[46] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-OIA Intl Education ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-112345 Academic Services Senior Prof Univ Staff - Academic Services 51 $33,150.00"      
[47] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-OIA Intl Education ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-120700 Business Services Director Univ Staff - Business Services 100 $102,857.00"       
[48] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-OIA Intl Education ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-116329 Business Services Professional Univ Staff - Business Services 100 $53,000.00"    
[49] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-OIA Intl Education ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-119938 Communication Director Univ Staff - Communication 100 $93,908.16"                
[50] "DENVER & ANSCHUTZ AVCASA-OIA Intl Education ACADEMIC & STUDENT AFFAIRS R21-115606 Assoc Vice Chancellor Univ Staff - Executive 100 $154,000.00"
```